# Set up Airflow production environment

Tags: airflow

I'm a newbie at using Airflow. I went through many Airflow tutorials, and I can say that all are about development environments using a docker-compose file or files. I'm facing a problem at work setting up a production environment properly. My goal is to have a cluster composed of 3 EC2 virtual machines. Can anyone share best practices for installing Airflow on that cluster?

I went through many tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow has 4 main components:

- Webserver: stateless service which expose the UI and the REST API of Airflow
- Scheduler: stateless service which processes the dags and runs them and it's the main component
- Worker: stateless service which execute the tasks
- Metadata: the database of Airflow where the state is stored, and it manages the communication between the 3 other components

And Airflow has 4 main executors:

- LocalExecutor: the scheduler runs tasks by itself by spawning a process for each task, and it works in a single host -> not suitable for your need
- CeleryExecutor: the most used scheduler, you can create one or multiple scheduler (for HA), and a group of celery workers to run the tasks, you can scale it on different nodes
- DaskExecutor: similar to CeleryExecutor but it uses Dask instead of Celery, not much used, and there is no many resources around it
- KubernetesExecutor: it runs each task in a K8S pod, and since it's based on Kubernetes, it's very scalable, but it has some drawbacks.

For you use case, I recommend using CeleryExecutor.

If you can use EKS instead of EC2, you can use the [helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) to install and configure the cluster. And if not, you have other options:

- run the services directly on the host:

  ```bash
  pip install apache-airflow[celery]
  # run the webserver
  airflow webserver
  # run the scheduler
  airflow scheduler
  # run the worker
  airflow celery worker
  ```

  You can decide how many scheduler, workers and webserver you want to execute, and you can distribute them on the 3 nodes, for ex: node1(1 scheduler, 1 webserver, 1 worker), node2(1 scheduler, 2 workers), node3(1 webserver, 2 workers), and you need a DB, you can use postgres from AWS RDS, or create it on one of the nodes (not recommended).
- using docker: same as the first solution, but your run containers instead of running the services directly on the host
- using docker swarm: you can connect the 3 nodes to create a swarm cluster, and manage the config from one of the nodes, this gives you some feature which are not provided by the first 2 solutions, and it's similar to K8S. ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/))

For the 3 solutions, you need to create `airflow.cfg` file contains the configurations and the DB creds, and you should set the [exeutor conf](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#executor) to `CeleryExecutor`.